# Asynchronous loading of partial view in Ember

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, ember.js

I've created an Ember helper to allow for loading a dynamically generated partial view from a URL on the server.  It looks like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('serverPartial', function(url, options) {
    var template;

    $.ajax(url, {
        async: false,
        success: function(templateText){
            template = Ember.Handlebars.compile(templateText);
        }
    });

    template(this, options);
});
```

And it's called from a parent Handlebars template like this:

```
{{serverPartial templateUrl}}
```

As you can see, the ajax call to retrieve the template from the server is a **synchronous** call, because I couldn't find any other way to return the template contents as expected by the Ember framework.  Unfortunately, this synchronous call holds up the rendering of the entire parent template.

Is there a way to return a promise for the template, or any other way to allow partial views to load asynchronously or independently?

Comment: why do you need to do a synchronous ajax call?

Comment: I'm trying to render some of my templates on the server because there are significant parts of my web application that are rendered using a server-side MVC framework, and I'm not ready to rewrite all of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the tip, @Rajat.  I did end up using `Views` to accomplish this.  I created a view container that initially loads a default child template, then that child loads in the actual contents from the server after it is inserted.  Here's the approach I took:

```
App.LoadingView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        var container = this._parentView;
        $.get('http://server/serverTemplate', function(data){
            container.pushObject(Ember.View.create({
                template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(data)
            }));
            container.removeObject(container.get('loadingView'));
        });
    },
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('client awesome')
});

// inherit from ContainerView and initialize with default content
App.SnippetView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    childViews: ['loadingView'],
    loadingView: App.LoadingView.create()
});
```

I'm sure there are better ways to express this, but does the job at a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

First, what you are trying to do with Handlebars helpers is not what they are intended to do. Handlebars helpers are strictly markup formatters and should be used for simple HTML adjustments.

Second, in typical ember apps, what you are trying to do is never done. There is no 'on-demand' fetching of templates.

This is because all templates are downloaded in one sweep when the app loads and live on client. They are precompiled to JavaScript functions and stored as `Strings` in the `Ember.Handlebars` hash.

They are downloaded when the app loads and then get evaluated when the view is rendered. In the meantime, they live simply as `Strings`.

Now if you still want to do what you are doing, I would recommend trying to do that in `Views`.

Comment: Thanks! For what it's worth, it looks like server-side template rendering *is* on the roadmap to be supported in the Ember core (http://tomdale.net/2013/09/maybe-progressive-enhancement-is-the-wrong-term/) so my usage case can't be totally off the mark.  Do you have any suggestions or references on how I might accomplish this functionality with Views instead?